# How do you create a JS code that randomly spreads objects

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making a simple code that you will have to put in the password and I would like to know how to make a code that will **randomly distribute text**. I have tried to use the push and pop methods.

```js
let sumbit;
let input;
let element;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);

  sumbit = createButton('Submit');
  sumbit.mousePressed(button);

  input = createInput();
  input.position(20, 60);

  element = createElement('h2', 'What is the password : ');
  element.position(5, 10);

  textSize(32);
}


function button() {
  const password = input.value();
  if(password == "2010") {
    element.html('Your Correct! ' + ' The password was ' + password);
  
  } else {
    element.html('Your incorrect the password was : 2010');
  }
  
  input.value('');
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**I would like the code to make the letters look something like this. I would appreciate some advice, Thank you in advance.**

[image]

Comment: are you sure you pasted the correct snippet? The code doesn't seem to be related to the question at all...

Comment: @georg I would like the end result to be like the image in the photo.

Comment: @OneShadow you said you "tried the push and pop" methods. Why don't you share that code in your question? As georg points out, the posted code appears to be mostly unrelated to your question, and it looks like you haven't made any effort whatsoever to implement what you are asking for. Also, bonus points if you include a runnable snippet in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- [`text()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text) to render each character
- [`random()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random) to pick a random position and angle (within a range)
- use other text related functions to adjust the look of the characters such as [`textFont()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textFont) to set a serif font and [`textSize()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textSize)

Here's a basic example with comments:

```js
let stringOfCharacters = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
let numLetters = 1000;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  // set serif font
  textFont('Times New Roman');
  
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numLetters; i++){
    // pick the next character from the string above, looping from the start when the i counter is greater or equal to the number of characters in the string
    let character   = stringOfCharacters.charAt(i % stringOfCharacters.length);
    // 50-50 change of pick a case
    character = random(0.0, 1.0) > 0.5 ? character.toUpperCase() : character.toLowerCase();
    // pick a random position
    let randomX     = random(0, width);
    let randomY     = random(0, height);
    // pick a random size
    let size        = random(12, 24);
    // pick a random angle (rember, by default, angles in p5 are in radians (though can be changed with angleMode(DEGREES)))
    let randomAngle = random(0, TWO_PI);
    // isolate the coordinate system to apply the rotation
    push();
    rotate(randomAngle);
    textSize(size);
    text(character, randomX, randomY);
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: individual letters rendered at random positions, rotations and sizes]

Instead of the 50-50 random condition you could go for a [dice roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musikalisches_W%C3%BCrfelspiel), starting off with a rectangular grid and slightly offsetting positions (which would reduce the likelihood of intersections), or any other random method.

There a few more options in p5 you could explore for randomness such as [Perlin `noise()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noise) or [`randomGaussian()` distribution](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/randomGaussian)